# Make Ubuntu with a hardware-protected USB pen drive safe

Tags: live-usb, read-only

I want to install Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on a USB pen drive which has a microswitch to make the USB pen drive hardware-protected read-only. My plan is to use the USB pen drive read-only in combination with several other USB pen drives with UnionFS (for every not trustable app there is a new USB pen drive). However, I want also to use the USB pen drive in read-write mode (without another USB pen drive attached) to update Ubuntu.

How can I achieve this?

I made two attempts, which failed:

1. installed Ubuntu on USB pen drive; It didn't booted in hardware-protected read-only mode.
2. made Live-USB with Ubuntu Startup Disc Creator on USB pen drive with 4GB persistence; I couldn't update Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu will not work on a read only device.

Comment: Live-USB works on a read only device

Comment: You can have persistent live systems with the partitions for persistence, the `casper-rw` partition on the other drives. As far as I know, you can only have one active `casper-rw` partition. It is possible to add a `home-rw` partition, where the `/home` directory will be stored (for persistence). But if you want to install in two steps, *safe updates & upgrades* and *installing not trustable application programs*, I have no good method except to **backup** the *safe updates & upgrades*, and **restore** it to the other drive, where you *install not trustable application programs*.

Comment: You can use mkusb to make a persistent live system, that works well with `casper-rw` partitions. See these links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/sp

Comment: Another alternative is to extend your alternative 1. installed Ubuntu on USB pen drive: Keep it up to date in one pendrive and create a compressed image, for example with Clonezilla.  Create cloned copies (from the image) and install your  *not trustable apps* into the cloned copies. I think the backup of this system will be slower than that of a persistent live system, but there will be more degrees of freedom and you will get a more stable system.